# Angular, Laravel - download files

Tags: php, angularjs

I have an aplication where I try to download files from server. In backend there is Laravel 5.2 but in frontEnd AngularJS 1.6.

Below I show my method in controller which should download files:

```
public function getCaseFile(Request $request){

            $caseId = $request->caseId;
            $fileId = $request->fileId;
            $path = $this->caseFiles->getCaseFilePath($caseId,$fileId);
            $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/png',
            ];

        return response()->download($path,"adsa.png",$headers);


    }
```

Route to that method is:

```
Route::get('/cic/upload/getCaseFile/{caseId}/{fileId}','\App\Http\Controllers\CicCore\UploadController@getCaseFile');
```

When I'm trying to get that file in browser, everything is ok. Below I show link:

```
http://dev.cic:8004/cic/upload/getCaseFile/232551/496
```

Problem is when I'trying download files in Angular application. [image]

Apllication is redirected to link:

```
http://dev.cic:8004/
```

I don't know what's wrong. Could someone has idea what is wrong with that? I would be very grateful for help. Best regards

Comment: Did you `$var_dump($request->caseId)` to check if the `caseId` and `fileId` come in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare your link like this:

```
<a target="_self" href="example.com/uploads/asd4a4d5a.pdf" download="fileuploader.png">fileuploader.png</a>
```

[Angular Doc Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting)